# Calling a OSX package from xcode c++ program terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

im planning to build a c++ application based on another c++ package (aria2c) i found over the internet which acts as a ready made wheel for me. I have already installed the package on my machine, but the problem is when i run `system("aria2c");`  it outputs "command not found", whereas if i run `system("git");` (which i have also installed) it will output the git's man page.

calling "brew" also doesnt work whereas git, ls and some other that i tried work.

So can someone explain to me why i cant access that package ? and if there is any solution to it ?

Comment: The most common mistake is that the pacakge might be installed for a particular user or at a particular path. Make sure that you have the library/application in your path list.

Comment: @Pradheep thanks for the quick response. Im pretty sure i have the correct user which is my user, but how do i make sure that i have the library/application in my path list ?

Comment: i would suggest first finding where the package is installed and then do echo $PATH in terminal to see if its in your path variable

Comment: @Pradheep thanks buddy, you saved the day.

Comment: i am adding it as answer , upvote it and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common mistake is that the pacakge might be installed for a particular user or at a particular path. Make sure that you have the library/application in your path list

To do that ,i would suggest first finding where the package is installed and then do echo $PATH in terminal to see if its in your path variable